# can chernoff bounds be used for proving upper bounds as well as lower bounds

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions

I have a hw problem where it is asked to show theta(n) using chernoff bounds. I am able to prove for O(n) but not in the reverse way.Is it possible to prove both bounds using chernoff?

Comment: What is the context? For eg, what is the hw problem?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like it works in both directions. I never used it in the case of lower bound, but here [Chernoff bound](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chernoff_bound) you can find example of usage as lower bound.

Let $X_{1}, ..., X_{n}$ be independent Bernoulli random variables, each having probability $p > 1/2$. Then the probability of simultaneous occurrence of more than $n/2$ of the events  has an exact value $P$.

The Chernoff bound shows that P has the following lower bound.

$P \geq 1 - e ^{-2n(p-\frac{1}{2})^2}$